# How to access the modal instance(s) that will be deleted in the 'before delete' operation hook?

Tags: loopbackjs

The `before save` and `after save` operation hooks have a `data` or `instance` property containing the partial data or model instance that's going to be changed. See [here](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Operation+hooks). How do I access the model instance in the `before delete` hook?

Case at hand: I want to delete related items when a specific model is deleted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have implemented this using the `before delete` observer too.

In this example there is a Category model that has a relation to many Products, related by the categoryId property.

It first searches for all matching Products based on the categoryId, and than loops over the result set `products` to delete them one by one.

```
module.exports = function (Category) {

Category.observe('before delete', function (ctx, next) {

    // It would be nice if there was a more elegant way to load this related model
    var Product = ctx.Model.app.models.Product;

    Product.find({
      where: {
        categoryId: ctx.where.id
      }
    }, function (err, products) {
      products.forEach(function (product) {
        Product.destroyById(product.id, function () {
          console.log("Deleted product", product.id);
        });
      });
    });

    next();
  });
};
```

I have tried to implement it using the [destroyAll](http://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#persistedmodel-destroyall) method, but that didn't give me the expected results.

Above code works for me, but it looks like it can be enhanced quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a modified version of jakerella's code using a findById, counting and deleting related items (in a 'hasMany' relation and named 'relatedItems'):

```
MyModel.observe('before delete', function(context, next) {
    console.log('About to delete some: ' + context.Model.pluralModelName);
    console.log('using the WHERE clause: ' + context.where);

    MyModel.findById(context.where.id, function(err, model) {
        console.log('found model:', model);

        model.relatedItems.count(function(err, count) {
            console.log('found ', count, ' related items');
        });
        model.relatedItems.destroyAll(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('found ', count, ' related items');
           }
        });

        next();   
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you actually get access to the specific instances being deleted, but you get access to the context object for the call, which includes a `where` property that identifies the instances that would be *selected* for deletion:

```
MyModel.observe('before delete', function(context, next) {
  console.log('About to delete some: ' + context.Model.pluralModelName);
  console.log('using the WHERE clause: ' + context.where);

  MyModel.find({ where: context.where }, function(err, models) {
    console.log('found some models:', models);

    // loop through models and delete other things maybe?
  });

  next();
});
```

This is in [the documentation](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Operation+hooks#Operationhooks-beforedelete), but not terribly well explained. You can use the `contect.Model` object to get an instance, then you have access to related models and you can delete them.

Comment: That could work. But what if I needed to find related items from a different model? I tried getting access to the model object using `app.models.OtherModel`, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

'this' is always accessible in all hooks(before or after).
In before destroy modelhook 'this' object will contain the modelInstances loopback is going to destroy.